# Comparison test for the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to test that the given series is convergent or divergent.

$\Sigma_{n=2}\frac {(-i)^n}{\ln n} $, ($z_n = \frac {(-i)^n}{\ln n}$)

I know that for $n >1 $, $\ln n< n$ holds. So by using the comparison test, $\Sigma_{n=2} \frac{1}{n} $ diverges so $\Sigma_{n=2}\frac {1}{\ln n} $ diverges too. But what about $\Sigma_{n=2}\frac {(-i)^n}{\ln n} $? I must check the divergence of series $z_n$, not for the series $|z_n|$ and I got confused...

p.s. When checking the convergence of series, it's quite obvious to only test for  the series $|z_n|$ case because absolute convergence implies convergence. But what about the divergence case?

Answer (score 1):

Your p.s. is wrong. There are series like $\sum (-1/n)^n$ which converge while the series of the absolute values diverges.

Your series is one of this. Indeed we can write
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^n}{\log (n)}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n}}{\log (2 n)}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}$$
The first one can be rewritten as
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{ n}}{\log (2 n)}$$
which converges for the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation) because general term tends to zero

The other series can be written as
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}=i\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}$$
which converges for the same test as above.