# Is the complex given series convergent or divergent? Give a reason. Show details.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Is the given series convergent or divergent? Give a reason. Show details.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n}{ln \ n}$$

So maybe I'll try using the ratio test?

So the series converges if $$\left| \frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n} \right| < 1$$

So I have that $$z_n = \frac{(-i)^{n+1}}{ln \ (n + 1)} \cdot \frac{ln \ n}{(-i)^n}$$

So I think the lns cancel right so all we're left with is an -i in the numerator? Is that right? Is that less than 1 so does it converge?

Comment: No, because $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln n / \ln(n+1) = 1$ by LHR.

Comment: This is a straightforward application of Dirichlet's Test.

 - Can you show there is some $M$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^{k}(-i)^n\right|\le M$ for any $k$?
 - Can you show $1/\ln n$ is monotone decreasing and convergent to zero?

If so, your series converges.

Comment: Is my ratio test wrong?

Comment: @Integrand that's why they cancel no?

Comment: It's not wrong but it's not helpful either; see my first comment. You *can* use RT for terms with polynomials, logs, arctan, etc. but if these are the *only* objects in your term it will be inconclusive.

Comment: Also, you should be taking absolute values; no $i$s should survive.

Comment: This is the same as this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901646/comparison-test-for-the-series

Comment: @Matematleta Just because the limit as n => goes to 0 doesn't mean it converges right? You have to show convergence... like the harmonic series terms go to 0 but the series doesn't converge right?

Comment: I have one answer that the series converges and another that says they do not, unsure what ot do.

Comment: @Matematleta are you signs wrong? It can't converge because 1/n < 1/ln(n) right?

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes, thanks for catching the typo! I will correct: Forget the ratio test. The series can not converge absolutely because $1/n<1/\ln n$

Comment: You got 11 gold badges and your OP still lacks MathJax as of today???

Answer (score 1):

The series converges by virtue of [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Your series actually represents two alternating series, one with a real component, and one with an imaginary component.

Both series converge because $(1/\log ~n)$ is strictly decreasing to zero.

Comment: Just because the limit as n => goes to 0 doesn't mean it converges right? You have to show convergence... like the harmonic series terms go to 0 but the series doesn't converge right?

Comment: @Jwan622 Wrong.  See the *alternating series test* link in my answer.   For an alternating series, if the absolute values of the terms are strictly decreasing and go to $0$, then you **automatically** know that the alternating series is convergent.

Comment: I see... does it satisfy the alternative series test for imaginary numbers? I can see why the right hand side passes with real numbers but not the left side.

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to by right hand side and left hand side.  The series can actually be represented by Series-1 $~+ (i \times $ Series-2), where Series-1 and Series-2 are each convergent alternating series of real numbers that converge (let's say) to $R,S$ (respectively).  Thus, the entire series converges to $R + iS.$

Comment: Can you give me the two series and I'll give you credit for the answer. Is there any other way to do this? Why does the ratio test not work here?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. Mind showing me both series and how this works?

Comment: @Jwan622 Let $R = - \frac{1}{\ln ~2} + \frac{1}{\ln ~4} - \frac{1}{\ln ~6} + \frac{1}{\ln ~8} \cdots$ and 
Let $S = + \frac{1}{\ln ~3} - \frac{1}{\ln ~5} + \frac{1}{\ln ~7} - \frac{1}{\ln ~9} \cdots$.
Then the series = $R + iS.$

Comment: and it converges because the function 1/log(n) is monotonic and converges to 0 right? that's sufficient? Does matter that i^n oscillates?

Comment: @Jwan622 Exactly, it's sufficient that 1/log(n) goes to 0.  However, it **does** matter that $i^n$ oscillates.  Assume that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive terms that is strictly decreasing and converges to 0.  In order to apply the Alternating Series test, the series **must** be formatted as $a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4 + \cdots.$

Answer (score 1):

we can write
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^n}{\log (n)}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n}}{\log (2 n)}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}$$
The first one can be rewritten as
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{ n}}{\log (2 n)}$$
which converges for the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation) because general term tends to zero

The other series can be written as
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-i)^{2 n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}=i\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\log (2 n+1)}$$
which converges for the same test as above.

Comment: yeah I just don't udnerstand this yet

Comment: Where does the 2n come from in the exponent?

Comment: @Jwan622 I separated even exponents from odd exponents