# Can you apply the ratio or root test to complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I do not know where to start these two questions:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(20 + 30i)^n}{n!}$$

My only tools on hand are the ratio test, root test, comparison test, and the divergence theorem that states that if the sequence of terms does not equal 0, then the series is divergent.

Can I do this any other way? Can I also see which magnitude is greater? So the magnitude of the numerator is $\left | (20 + 30i)^n\right | = \sqrt{400 + 900}^n = 36.055^n$  and  so $$\lim_{n=0}^\infty \frac{36.055^n}{n!} = 0 $$ because n! grows faster. can I solve it this way? What is this called?

What about this one?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-i)^n}{\ln{n}}$$

Comment: The ratio and root tests are tests for absolute convergence. They do not distinguish between $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(\lvert a_n\rvert)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Hence they work for complex numbers just as they do for real numbers. Your last example is not absolutely convergent, so that needs a different test. Dirichlet's test for example.

Comment: For the second one look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3908955/is-the-complex-given-series-convergent-or-divergent-give-a-reason-show-details/3909569#3909569

Comment: @DanielFischer is your point that because the series switches between negative and positive, I cannot use the ratio and root tests but something else? What is your notation?

Comment: No, my point is that for $\sum \frac{(-i)^{n}}{\ln n}$ you cannot use the ratio or root test because that series is only conditionally convergent. (And ratio and root tests are inconclusive for it, so they do not even allow you to conclude that this series isn't absolutely convergent. For that, you need a different argument too. Comparison is easy, but e.g. Raabe's test would also settle it.) So to deal with that series, you need a test for not-necessarily-absolute convergence. // Not sure which notation you mean, $\lvert z\rvert$ is the modulus of a complex (or real) number.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you could only use those two tests if the series absolutely converges. How would I know this and whether to apply them or not? I now know that: ""Absolute convergence" means a series will converge even when you take the absolute value of each term, while "Conditional convergence" means the series converges but not absolutely."

Comment: Well, pedantically, "you cannot use" isn't quite correct. You can use, but they won't help. With enough experience, you can often see quickly which test/criterion is the most convenient to apply. To gather enough experience, apply tests to series you come across, starting with the simplest tests, proceeding to more advanced tests, until you find one that works (conclusively answers the question of convergence) or until you're fed up (this is not an option if it is *important* to determine convergence or divergence of the series).

Comment: So can you walk me a little more slowly why I can't apply either root or ratio here?