# Does this imaginary series really diverge?

Tags: divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{(-i)^{n}}{\ln n}}$$
In the answer, using comparison test $1/\ln n > 1/n,$ the series is divergent.
But, in my opinion, the series can be divided like
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln (2n)}}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\ln (2n+1)}}$$
Then, each series converges, so the series should converge.
What is the correct answer?

Comment: Second one is correct. Your application of Comparison test is wrong. It only shows that the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3908955/42969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n=\frac 1{\ln n}$ is monotically tends to zero. For $b_n=(-i)^n$ we have $|\sum_{n=2}^N b_n|\leq\sqrt2$ for any $N\geq 2.$ So, according to [Dirichlet Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test),
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nb_n=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-i)^n}{\ln n}$$
converges.

Comment: OP already  has a simpler argument to prove convergence.

Comment: @geetha290krm His solution is using Dirichlet test two times, mine is using once.

Comment: His proof uses Alternating Series Test (AST) for each of the two terms. The two links provided by Martin R also use AST.